# The free smooth path space on a manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fibre-bundles, loop-spaces

Let $M$ be a closed, smooth manifold and let $PM$ be the space of unbased piecewise smooth paths $[0,1] \to M$. Then restricting a path to its boundary gives a map
$$
PM \to M \times M .
$$

**Question** is this map a fiber bundle?

Andrew Stacey showed that a related map, the free smooth loop fibration $LM \to M$, is a fiber bundle (see *The differential topology of loop spaces*, arXiv:[math/0510097](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510097)). However, an inspection of his method shows that it does not immediately adapt to the situation above.

Comment: I think Andrew told me this was true, but I can't recall where or how (I can't find an email about it). As far as the reference goes, it looks somewhat implicit: on page 4 Andrew says how section 5 proves $ev\colon LM  \to M$ is locally trivial, as a consequence of general results, but section 5 is not forthcoming (on a quick scan) as to how.

Comment: I'd go so far as to tentatively claim that $PM \to M \times M$ is probably locally homotopy trivial, at least in the case where $PM$ is the space of smooth maps, but I'd have to think a bit more as to why.

Comment: Hi John. Firstly, feel free to email me directly: loopspace-usual symbol-mathforge-next usual symbol-org. Secondly, piecewise-smooth is problematic: see my article in Glasgow Math, also on arxiv, on that.  With smooth, then PM -> MxM is locally trivial for the same reasons as 5.1, but the fibre is not LM. This is also covered in "Yet more smooth mapping spaces .." Prop 3.12.  If you clarify what form of smooth mapping space you're happy with, I'll try to tidy that up into an answer.

Comment: I forget which article is in Glasgow Math and it might not be the one I meant.  All my relevant articles are on the arXiv.

Comment: @LoopSpace Andrew,  I am primarily interested in the piecewise smooth case. But even in the smooth case, I don't understand why your method should adapt. The problem I have is this: if $(x,y) \in M \times M$ is a  point and $(x',y')$ is nearby, then we will necessarily have to deform a smooth path from $x$ to $y$  to a smooth path from $x'$ to $y'$. In your paper, you use a flow on a chart at $x$ to accomplish this when $x=y$ and $x'=y'$. But when $x=y$ and $x'\ne y'$ (i.e., start with a loop and end with a non-loop) then your flow will not work in this case.

Comment: For a connected manifold $N$ and points $p,q \in N$ then there is a path of diffeomorphisms (with compact support) starting at the identity and ending at a diffeomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(p) = q$.  This is what is needed to establish the local triviality of the fibre bundle. Now apply that to $N = M \times M$ and you'll get the result you need.  The point is that the diffeomorphism is of $M \times M$ and not of $M$.

Comment: With regard to piecewise-smooth, you first have to decide what "piecewise-smooth" means as that's not a well-defined term.  Then, you have to decide what you're prepared to live without: piecewise-smooth gives you some nice properties, but also a lot of bad stuff (I'm not convinced that the space is smoothly regular - has partitions of unity) such as losing the niceness of the natural circle action. Piecewise-smooth used to be seen as a way round some issues with smoothness and gluing, but I've always thought of it as a cure worse than the disease.

Comment: But without knowing the motivation for the question I can't advise you as to the advisability of using piecewise-smooth.

Comment: @LoopSpace My reason for concentrating on in the piecewise smooth case is related to Milnor's approximation to the loop space in Morse theory which involves piecewise smooth loops.  I can tell you more about it in an email at some point.

Anyway, I should think that a map $\gamma: [0,1]\to M$ is piecewise smooth if there is a subdivision $0=t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n < t_{n+1}=1$ such that the restriction of $\gamma$ to each $[t_k,t_{k+1}]$ is smooth. Isn't that the usual thing?

Comment: @JohnKlein The question is as to what you mean by smooth on a closed interval.  Do the derivatives exist at the end points?  Anyway, I've answered (I think!) your actual question.  I'd love to hear more, but email might be better than comments here.

Comment: Smooth on a closed interval $[a,b]$ for me means that there is an extension to a smooth map on $(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

Comment: That's equivalent to bounded derivatives because the restriction map $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ splits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

The technical details are in *[Yet More Smooth Mapping Spaces and Their Smoothly Local Properties](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5493)*, specifically in Section 5 which establishes that smooth manifolds are *smoothly locally deformable* which means that there are lots of diffeomorphisms flying around.
Interestingly, although I considered subspaces I didn't consider spaces over other spaces.  Nonetheless, the same technology allows us to do so.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.  Section 5 of *Yet More ...* shows that $M$ is *smoothly locally deformable*.  In the discussion preceding Proposition 3.12 it is shown that this means that there is a neighbourhood $M \subseteq V \subseteq M \times M$ and a smooth map $\phi \colon \mathbb{R} \times V \to \operatorname{Diff}(M)$ with the following properties:

1. For $v \in V$, $t \mapsto \phi_{t,v}$ is a group homomorphism $(\mathbb{R},+) \to \operatorname{Diff}(M)$.
2. For $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v = (x,y) \in V$, $\phi_{t,v}$ is the identity outside $V_x := \{x' : (x,x') \in V\}$.
3. For $v = (x,y) \in V$, $\phi_{1,v}(y) = x$.

Now let $T$ be a compact smooth space and $S \subseteq T$ a compact subset.  We assume that there is a neighbourhood $S \subseteq U \subseteq T$ with a retraction $\tau \colon U \to S$, and a bump function $\sigma \colon T \to [0,1]$ such that $\sigma(S) \subseteq \{1\}$ and $\overline{\sigma^{-1} (0,1]} \subseteq U$.

Fix a class of function that is closed under diffeomorphism and which satisfies a sheaf condition in that functions can be defined locally.

Let $\alpha \colon S \to M$ be a function.  Define $C\big((S,T),(V,M)\big)_\alpha$ to be the space of functions $\beta \colon T \to M$ with the property that $(\alpha, \beta\mid_S)$ maps $S$ into $V$.  Define $C(T,M)_\alpha$ to be the space of functions $\beta \colon T \to M$ such that $\beta\mid_S = \alpha$.  Define $C(S,V)_\alpha$ to be the space of functions $\beta \colon S \to M$ such that $(\alpha,\beta)$ maps $S$ into $V$ (I'm not sure my notation is the best here!).

We define $\Phi \colon C\big((S,T), (V,M)\big)_\alpha \to C(T,M)_\alpha \times C(S,V)_\alpha$ as follows.  The map to the second factor is simply the restriction to $S$.  The map to the first factor takes a function $\beta \colon T \to M$ to the function:

$$
t \mapsto \begin{cases}
\phi_{\sigma(t), (\alpha(\tau(t)), \beta(\tau(t)))}\big(\beta(t)\big) & t \in U \\\\
\beta(t) & t \notin U
\end{cases}
$$

The conditions on $\phi$ mean that this patches together to give a well-defined function.  The inverse of $\Phi$ takes a pair $(\beta,\gamma)$ to:

$$
t \mapsto \begin{cases}
\phi_{-\sigma(t), (\alpha(\tau(t)),\gamma(\tau(t)))}\big(\beta(t)\big) & t \in U \\\\
\beta(t) & t \notin U
\end{cases}
$$

The case in point uses piecewise-smooth functions, $T = [0,1]$ and $S = \{0,1\}$.    The conditions are easily checked.

**Further Reading**

1. *[The differential topology of loop spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510097)*, particularly Proposition 5.1.  This contains the germ of the idea.
2. *[Yet More Smooth Mapping Spaces and Their Smoothly Local Properties](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5493)*, this contains the technical results needed.  Proposition 3.12 is quite close to what you need here.  This would establish that $LM \subseteq PM$ has a tubular neighbourhood, which says that it is a bundle on a neighbourhood of a diagonal.  Interestingly, I didn't consider fibrations of mapping spaces.  Maybe I should add another section ...
3. *[The Smooth Structure of the Space of Piecewise-Smooth Loops](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0611)* about piecewise-smooth maps.

Comment: Andrew, I plan to read your paper. However,  I do not need a manifold structure or a partition of unity structure on the space of piecewise smooth paths. What I do require is the evident diffeology.

Comment: Yes, it sounds as though you're less interested in the space in and of itself and more in relation to other, better behaved, spaces.  Some uses of piecewise-smooth require it to be a manifold in and of itself and that's what my work focusses on, and I'm aware that that structure is often glossed over which is why I tend to get a bit emphatic when talking about piecewise-smooth stuff!  My apologies if my tone was a bit over the top with that.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Andrew, upon reflection, I have some reservations. Your displayed recipe for the trivialization isn't clear to me: $\gamma$ is a map $I \to M$, not $I \to M \times M$, so the composition $\Psi(\gamma(0),\gamma(1)) \circ \gamma$ does not make sense.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'll have a think about it.

Comment: Okay, I can fix this.  It'll have to wait until later, but the idea is to pick different diffeos of M for $\gamma(1)$ and $\gamma(0)$ and then apply these diffeos at the different ends of the path.

Comment: @LoopSpace Does this argument work with stronger regularity, for instance the smooth case? Or intermediate, say $C^k$ but piecewise smooth? EDIT: i just you mentioned this above! Excellent :-)

Comment: @LoopSpace Hmmm...what if the ends of the path coincide?

Comment: @JohnKlein See update.

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks. It looks right to me now.

Comment: @JohnKlein I've updated it again to generalise it.  I'm considering adding this version to my paper.

Comment: That's great! I can cite you then.